# Lower-case the main navigation buttons

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

It would be extra nice to lower-case the **/Questions**, **/Tags**, **/Users**, ... text, just to fit in with the Unix philosophy (**/etc**, **/usr**, **/home**, ...). I'm even thinking that **/Ask Question** should be something like **/ask_question**, so that the shell won't complain :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will be in the next build.

Comment: this is a small issue: __/ask question__ --> __/ask_question__, so ignore it if it's just nit-picking

Comment: @Tshepang that fix is also on the way. the dev team is taking care of that.

Comment: I actually believe that the "ask question" button is very hard to spot for a new user..